# Excel/VBA Worksheet_Change repeating throughout

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet_change macro running. What I want it to do is check when a user pastes values from another workbook that they match certain criteria. For example, if an end user pastes into column A(which starts at A18), which is the Title column, his values will be rejected unless they meet values on another worksheet "Drop Down Menus" under the title column C. Etc. There are several rows throughout the worksheet which needs to be matched.

What happens now is if I post values in columns A - E, and the value in A18 is not a valid Title, I get the message box "Value in cell must be a valid "Title" for A18, B18, C18, D18, and E18, and then if E18 is not a valid type it goes back and tells me A18 is not valid as well. I feel this is an application.enable = false type solution, but cannot figure it out.

Thanks

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Insures values in column A are from Title List
    Dim Title As Range
    Set Title = Worksheets("DATA INPUT SHEET").Range("A18:A100000")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Title) Is Nothing Then
'
        For Each c In Target
            Set TitleLst = Worksheets("DROP DOWN MENUS").Range("C2:C1000").Find(c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
            If TitleLst Is Nothing And c <> "" Then
                 Application.EnableEvents = False
                MsgBox "The value at " & c.Address(False, False) & " must be a valid " & Worksheets("DROP DOWN MENUS").Range("C1"), vbOKOnly + vbCritical
                c.ClearContents
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next
    End If
 'Insures values in column E are from Recipient List
    Dim Recipient As Range
    Set Recipient = Worksheets("DATA INPUT SHEET").Range("E18:E100000")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Recipient) Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In Target
            Set RecipientLst = Worksheets("DROP DOWN MENUS").Range("D2:D1000").Find(c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
            If RecipientLst Is Nothing And c <> "" Then
                MsgBox "The value at " & c.Address(False, False) & " must be a valid " & Worksheets("DROP DOWN MENUS").Range("D1"), vbOKOnly + vbCritical
                c.ClearContents
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks
Matt

Comment: You're already doing Application.EnableEvents = False for the first clearContents. Is there any reason you don't do the same for the second instance?

Comment: Why not just use input validation?

Comment: You're checking the Intersect is not nothing, but then looping through the entire Target range, which may include cells not (eg) in ColA or E.  Instead, set a range to the Intersect, and loop over that.

Comment: Mikegrann - I didn't use it in the second instance because it didn't seem to have an effect in the first instance.

Comment: @Raystafarian We do have that for individual cells, but for copy - paste operations validation is destroyed.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks, I believe this is the answer I am going to use. It's not perfect in my opinion, but it works. Not perfect because of my implementation, not your suggestion. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your validation code is almost identical between the two checks, I would put it into a separate sub and call it from the event handler.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ShtDDM As Worksheet

    Set ShtDDM = Worksheets("DROP DOWN MENUS")

    'in a worksheet module you can use "Me" to refer to the worksheet
    ValidateValues Application.Intersect(Me.Range("A18:A100000"), Target), _
                   ShtDDM.Range("C2:C1000"), _
                   ShtDDM.Range("C1")

    ValidateValues Application.Intersect(Me.Range("E18:E100000"), Target), _
                   ShtDDM.Range("D2:D1000"), _
                   ShtDDM.Range("D1")

End Sub

Sub ValidateValues(rngInput As Range, rngLookup As Range, sType As String)
    Dim c As Range, f As Range, isect As Range
    If Not rngInput Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rngInput.Cells
            If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                Set f = rngLookup.Find(c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                                   MatchCase:=False)
                If f Is Nothing Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    MsgBox "The value at " & c.Address(False, False) & _
                            " must be a valid " & sType, vbOKOnly + vbCritical
                    c.ClearContents
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End If     'has a value
        Next c
    End If             'any intersect?
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked so well and is an elegant design as well. I have about 15 data validations throughout the worksheet and this is so much more compact and beautiful than calling them all separately. Thank you so much!

Comment: You might consider incorporating @cyboashu's suggestion of only showing the message box once per run: if someone were to paste in 50 invalid values then that's a lot of message boxes...